# Usage of "If" and "will" together

Tags: conditionals, will-future

Can you use the following phrase ...

> 1. Please let me know if you **will be available** to attend.

I'm hung up on the "will be" part.

I know there are other versions, which are equally as useful, specifically

> 2. Please let me know if you **are available** to attend.

The following phrase is also acceptable.

> 3. Please let me know if you **will attend**

Is sentence No.1 grammatically correct? I'm just looking for proper clarification.

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking what the meaning of the first sentence is? Are you asking whether the last cited sentence is grammatical and meaningful? Are you asking whether the two mean the same thing? Unclear.

Comment: The question is whether or not the 1st phrase is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: The answer to that question is yes. It is grammatical and meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is in any way related to the possibility of using "if" with "will", I'd like to make clear that the sentences in question are not conditional: "if" introduces a content clause, which can be replaced with a pronoun like "something" (Please let me know **something**). The fact that the clauses are not conditional can also be proved by the possibility of substituting "whether" for "if": Please let me know **whether** you will attend...

Therefore, there are no restrictions as to the use of the future after "if" in this case.

As regards the meaning of sentence No. 1, the speaker is clearly asking the interlocutor about his/her **future** availability to attend, similar to: I want to know if/whether **it will be possible for you to attend**. "You" may be available to attend in the future and end up not attending after all.